# Nagios Scaling factor

Tags: monitor, nagios

Im tring to run ore Nagios 3.5.1 on a bigger screen. Im not edit manual the scaling factor to 1.4 but after a refresh this will go back to normal 1.0. Searching on the internet but so for no luck.

Internet says about that you need a statusmap.c but i did a yum install nagios from the epel repo. 
So there is no statusmap.c only a statusmap.cgi. Tried to edid the value:

```
input type='text' name='scaling_factor' maxlength='5' size='4' value='%2.1f'
```

Still no luck. Is there a way to add a **static** scaling factor 1.4 that would not change after a refresh off the page?

kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.  I found that you can load the statusmap URL directly by adding "/cgi-bin/statusmap.cgi" to the base nagios URL.  You can also pass in the scaling_factor as an argument to this CGI:

/cgi-bin/statusmap.cgi?scaling_factor=1.4

The scaling factor will now persist for each page update.